# Using QTranslator in static Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization

I am writing an open source application, licensed under GPL. It is linked statically with Qt5 to work in environments without Qt installed (such as Windows and OS X).

It is using QTranslator for i18n support. [Documentation says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html#enabling-translation), that we need `.qm` files, built by the application developer and some `qt_<lang>.qm`, provided by Qt itself and installed in the system path.

Should we provide the `qt_<lang>.qm` files in static distribution by ourselves or some Qt magic does it by itself?

Comment: You should provide them.

Comment: Well, then we'll embed them in `.qrc` file along with other `.qm` files, thanks!